# Use style property of an element as condition in if or for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am having problems understanding condition in If statement [or For lopp]. I created div that plays like Menu button. When I click that div all menu including this Menu button is shown but also text [paragraph inside div] changes to "Close menu". I tried to make some if condition in function that is fired up when I click Menu button but it looks like if condition doesn't work like I want to.  Here is an example in for loop:

```
function Show_mobile_menu() {
for (;  document.getElementById("Menu_button").style.cssText ="align-self:flex-end;" ; ) {
Func1(); }
}
for (; document.getElementById("Menu_button").style.cssText ="align-self: center;"; ) {
Func2(); }
}

function Func1() {
    document.getElementById("Menu").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("Submenu").style.display = "flex"; 
    document.getElementById("Menu_button").style.cssText ="align-self: center;"
    document.getElementById("Menu_button").getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML ="Close";   
}

function Func2() {
    document.getElementById("Menu").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Submenu").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById("Menu_button").style.cssText ="align-self: flex-end;"
    document.getElementById("Menu_button").getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML ="Menu"; 
}
```

Of course same thing is with if condition:

```
   if ( document.getElementById("Menu_button").style.cssText ="align-self:flex-end;" == true) {
        Func1();
    }
```

I tried the same with if textContent = "Menu" then do that... But nothing. As you can see I am learning JavaScript and syntax and meaning still isn't quite clear. I hope someone could clear things up for me.

Comment: First of all, `=` will assign the value to the variable. You want to use `==` when you are checking for equality.

Comment: Second, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with those `for` loops. You probably just want to use `if` statements. Third, that `if` statement you show should be `if (document.getElementById("Menu_button").style.cssText == "align-self:flex-end;")`. Fourth, you should use the debugger in your browser and set a break point at that `if` statement, and see what `cssText` actually equals.

Comment: Ok @forgivenson , why is this wrong, that is why it doesn't work:           `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
    <style>
h1 {
background-color:pink;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="Button" onclick="Test();">Click me!</button>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<script>
function Test() {
var Element = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
if (Element.style.backgroundColor == "pink") {
    Element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

If you want get style of an element you have to use proper methods. I found it on MDN site.

**Simple example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
h1 {
background-color:pink;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="Button" onclick="Test();">Click me!</button>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<script>
function Test() {
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
var stil = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-color"); 
    if (stil == "rgb(255, 192, 202)") {
        alert("OK");
    } else {
        alert("Not ok")
    }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You get value in rgb form.